# php-cgi.exe CPU load jumps after MySQL Backup

Tags: mysql, php, iis, cpu-usage

I'm running Windows 2012r2 on a new server, with Plesk 12.5 and MySQL 5.6 installed.

There's a backup script which takes a DB dump and zips website data files that runs each day. However, it brings the server to a crawl while it runs - but more confusingly even after it has finished.

There are lots of cgi-php.exe processes (for PHP 7 and 5.6 under IIS) that shoot up to consume almost all of the CPU load, and they'll stay there until I restart MySQL... That's what I find so confusing. The MySQL CPU load is very low, but it fixes the php problem when restarting.

How can I begin to troubleshoot this problem? Is there something related to MySQL that could cause a backlog with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like PHP process gets hung during the interaction with MySQL. I would suggest enabling slow queries and trace the time taking queries.

Comment: Thanks, I've enabled the slow query log in MySQL, but the only transaction is the HUGE mysqldump query that takes place, which causes the problem. I could understand it if PHP was slow during the backups, but improved afterwards - but it's slow after too. The backup size (30GB) exceeds the innodb buffer pool size (20GB), so I thought it may have something to do with removing old data from the buffer after the backup?